# page factory pattern and dropdownlist

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, findby

I am a novice in selenium.

I need some help trying to do this.

how do I use page factory pattern to select a drop down list

the code I tried is not working

I am getting an error saying annotation name expected instead

```
@FindBy(how=How.ID,using="ccompound")    
public WebElement Select_Compound;
Select dropDownBox = new Select(Select_Compound);
dropDownBox.selectByVisibleText("monthly")
```

thanks

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: I am using eclipse ee Ide. The error is saying " syntax error on token annotation name expected instead"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the last 2 statements to the test method. That's why you get the syntax error.

```
Select dropDownBox = new Select(Select_Compound);
dropDownBox.selectByVisibleText("monthly");
```

The last statement can not exist outside the method.